# set object properties when every() on array return false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia, ecmascript-5

I've finally used another logic (using "let" with break), but I would be happy to have (if it's feasible) another solution:
I've built a validation service which iterate over (injected) list of objects that contains regex expressions and relevant message (and input element) for each expression. I'm using every() method to iterate over the regex expressions. The service  knows to return true or false when testing the regex.
The problem is that except for getting true\false I would like the consumer of the service to get the relevant message and the input element. So, in the service class I have 2 properties (lets call them "message" and "element") and I thought to set them accordingly. But, when I'm in the context of the every - the "this" refer to the context and not to the class. I thought of sending those 2 properties as parameters to the every method. Is that the best practice? 
See relevant code:

```
export class userValidation 
{
    constructor() {
       this.validationMessage = '';
       this.validationElement = '';
//}

validateByExpression(elementValidator, valueToValidate, functionToExec) {
  var validationMessage = this.validationMessage;//Trying to get reference -  no go
   if (elementValidator.regex.test(valueToValidate) == false) 
   {
     //This is the part where I need to store\return the relevant message
     validationMessage = elementValidator.message; // fails
     return false;
   }  
   else 
   {
     return true;
   }
  }
  validate(validationElement, elementName, valueToValidate) 
  {
    var regexExpList = new Array(validationElement);
    var getValidationMessage = this.getValidationMessage;
    var validateByExpression = this.validateByExpression;
    var validationMessage = this.validationMessage;
    return regexExpList.every(function(regexExp) { return 
     getValidationMessage(validateByExpression, regexExp[elementName],         
     valueToValidate, validationMessage) });
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not set `userValidation.validationMessage`? What is purpose for using `.every()` if you intend to get individual property values of elements of array?

Comment: @guest271314 - my mistake -I modified the code - the validateByExpression function is part of the userValidation class.I also added the part of iteration using every (I need to get the first regex message that fails the validation, that's why I'm using every() method)